# Could not find artifact org.jboss.seam:jboss-seam:jar:2.3.5.Final-redhat-1 in central

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, artifact

I am using maven to add dependency. I added

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.seam/jboss-seam -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
   <artifactId>jboss-seam</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.5.Final-redhat-1</version>
</dependency>
```

jboss-seam jar by using above lines in pom.xml. When I run `mvn clean install` it gives an error

[image]

What is the issue and how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the below repository in your pom file,

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>redhat</id>
        <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

The artifact is not available in maven central repository. Its available only in redhat-ga repository.

Comment: Above lines work for this jboss-seam redhat jar but I have lot of others jar also which has same problem. So can you tell me from where I got this repository links for other jar ?

Comment: You can see in the link (mvnrepository.com) itself the there will be a column called Repositories which will contain the list of repos for the mentioned artifact. Please note, you need to mention it only If the specified artifact is not available in the central repo.